# Which is better in performance client side joins or server side joins

Tags: mysql, join, nosql, rdbms

If I have 2 tables **employee** and **department**

1) to join data at the server side

```
SELECT * FROM employee CROSS JOIN department;
```

we use only one connection here to grab the data

2) to join data at client side we would grab the 2 tables and use 2 connections

```
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

and store it in an array and also

```
SELECT * FROM department;
```

and store it in another array and and merge the 2 arrays by programming at the client side using for example Javascript.

the second method may be more complex but the advantages is that you could store the employee table on one sever and the department table on another server by this you decrease the load on your own server and make the each client machine do its work

But I'm asking if I want to join 2000 table Which would be better in performance and faster: to do joins at the client side or at the server side?

Comment: What a bad set of tags. Please focus on *one* database approach. In any case, **performing the join the server is [almost] always better** (years of optimizations, smart query plans, index usage, multiple join implementations, less requests, smaller data transmission, etc)  - and I would have to have a very specific case (backed by empirical evidence) before I decided to do differently. Use the tools as they were meant to be used. (However, this simple CROSS JOIN - ick! - throws a slight twist on the question.)

Comment: Why is this question tagged MongoDB?

Comment: I'm planing to store the reletional data as documents in collections in MongoDB and do the joins at the client side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question (though with bad tags, as has been pointed out).

The join would definitely be faster if done at the server, but if each table had just 1,000 rows your result set would be 1,000,000 rows, and those have to be sent back to the client. If you join at the client, you're only sending back 2,000 rows. Depending on what you need to do at the client side, it might be worth doing separate queries to cut down on the traffic between client and server. Then again, joining the two sets with JavaScript won't be fast either.

So here's the squishy answer: It all depends on the result set size; you'll have to experiment.

Note this answer holds for `CROSS JOIN` only. All other join types are best done at the server, no question.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, it's far better to do the join on the server side.

Doing the join on the client side requires transferring *all* the data from both tables to the client, even when the join condition will subsequently eliminate a large majority of rows from both tables.  You'll be wasting a lot of network bandwidth for every such query.

Also note that joins on the server side should be better at performance because they can use indexes to look up matching rows.  If you store the data in arrays on the client side, you don't get the benefit of indexed lookups.  The best you can do is make sure that both arrays are sorted by their respective join columns, and then you can do the join in a single pass.

You're right that doing the joins on the client-side allows you to join tables that live on separate servers, but I would claim that if you have related data that is valid to join, it should live on the same server.  Not only to support joins, but also to support referential integrity, transactions, etc.

PS:  I have no idea why you tagged your question with mongodb and nosql.  Your question seems to have nothing to do with non-relational databases.

PPS: The answer from @EdGibbs reminds me that you presented CROSS JOIN as the alternative.  Using CROSS JOIN should be a very rare thing to do, and is probably not what you want in the example of departments and employees.  You would instead want to use the join to identify matches, i.e. employees who belong to a given department.